# when trying to use several pipes in angular 2 I get 'parse errors'

Tags: angular, pipes-filters

When i'm using the 'async' pipe, with another pipe, in my example the 'order by' pipe, my code stops working and I get a 'parse error'.
Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

[my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CpnpytPlLl3iWok8mhm?p=preview)

```
<tr *ngFor="#team of teams | orderBy:'-points';#i = index | async">...
```

Answer (score 0):

the `async` is misplaced:

```
<tr *ngFor="#team of teams | async | orderBy:'-points';#i = index">
```

Comment: now it says that it can't read the property of null. how can I overcome it?

Comment: Can you post your component code? I suspect your teams is empty

Comment: It doesn't run because you miss import of `Input` in your squad component. See if things work after you added it. Check your console to make sure you have no errors